# Java - run an executable from a Java class that can be passed a file from memory instead of the filesystem

Tags: java, parameters, process, runtime, filestream

I'm currently running an executable from a Java class that takes a configuration file as one of it's parameters.

The code, which is working, looks like this:

```
String[] params = new String[3];

params[0] = "myProgram.exe";
params[1] = "--cf";
params[2] = "myConfiguration.cf";

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(params);

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

input.close();
```

For security purposes, I'd like to create the configuration file inside the Java class, and provide it to the runtime as an in-memory stream instead of an external file.

Is this possible? I don't have control over the executables code, so I'm not clear if there's a way to make it see the filename as anything different than a file that it has to retrieve from disk.

Comment: Do you know if the executable can read from `stdin`?  Some programs indicate this with something like `myProgram --cf -` or something similar.  In that case you could pipe to it.

Comment: Windows doesn't support pipes, or rather only does so via a temp file trick so the answer to @stdunbar's question might be no. You could nevertheless write to a temporary file then delete it

Comment: Huh? NT (whence modern Windows) has always supported pipes as pipes.  [Win32 doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/about-pipes).

Comment: No , this is not possible if this executable lookup the file in the file system. but If this executable is flexible even to read a named pipe, then this is practical, but creating a named pipe  using a java code in windows is not that easy, you have to use JNA ,

Comment: @undefinedsymbol     I'm talking about çmd.exe sorry, not Windows per se. I *think* the pipe character is implemented using temporary files.

Comment: cmd.exe was written for NT, so they'd be nutty to not use an NT OS feature.  Do not confuse with the DOS command.com.